# Wrap text in flexbox, but maintain relative column width for different lengths of text

Tags: css, flexbox, word-wrap

I'm using flexbox for a Wordpress site. 
Two columns, child 1 should be 75% of the page, child 2 25%.
With a small sentence in child 1 it works, however, with a large text it pushes child 1 to 100% page width. The long text may not push the div to 100% but wrap inside the div. See the jsfiddle example below.
How can I fix this? Quite new at this. Tnx!

http://jsfiddle.net/luchtrat/jnys3u5p

```css
body *{border: 1px solid red;} /* just to preview what's happening */

#parent {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex-flow: row wrap;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  padding: 10px;
}
#child_1 {
  flex-grow: 2;
}
#child_2 {
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <div id="child_1">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque aliquam dapibus volutpat. Proin suscipit massa at ipsum semper, et pretium ante bibendum. Vivamus justo erat, aliquet maximus turpis quis, sagittis tempor lectus. Nullam eleifend, nisi
    vitae condimentum elementum, arcu sapien finibus nisl, sit amet euismod nibh felis quis turpis. Fusce nec egestas sapien, non ultricies ligula. Aliquam ac libero elementum, rhoncus massa quis, posuere massa.
  </div>
  <div id="child_2">Fusce nec egestas sapien.</div>
</div>
<div id="parent">
  <div id="child_1">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</div>
  <div id="child_2">Fusce nec egestas sapien.</div>
</div>
```

Comment: And your code is where?

Comment: Use `flex-wrap: wrap;` in your css.

Comment: Code & link added.

Answer (score 2):

- Don't duplicate ID. ID should be unique per page. Use classes instead:
- Use simply: `flex:2;` and `flex:1` respectively for your `child_` elements
  or better `flex:3` if you want to get `75%` → `25%` as desired

```css
body * {border: 1px solid red;}

.parent {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  padding: 10px;
}
.child_1 {
  flex: 3; /* "75%" */
}
.child_2 {
  flex: 1; /* "25%" */
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child_1">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque aliquam dapibus volutpat. Proin suscipit massa at ipsum semper, et pretium ante bibendum. Vivamus justo erat, aliquet maximus turpis quis, sagittis tempor lectus. Nullam eleifend, nisi
    vitae condimentum elementum, arcu sapien finibus nisl, sit amet euismod nibh felis quis turpis. Fusce nec egestas sapien, non ultricies ligula. Aliquam ac libero elementum, rhoncus massa quis, posuere massa.
  </div>
  <div class="child_2">Fusce nec egestas sapien.</div>
</div>
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child_1">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</div>
  <div class="child_2">Fusce nec egestas sapien.</div>
</div>
```

Comment: It's really weird - when adding the code above to my wordpress php files; it doesn't work.

Comment: @JeroenPede have you added all the `-vendor-` prefixes? (I removed them  just for simplicity)

Comment: Yes, I did. When trying your code in jsfiddle as a test, it works out fine. When copy pasting in my wordpress css & php file, it's not working.

Comment: @JeroenPede inspect element and see what styles are overwritten (crossed-out) by other classes / rules.

Comment: @JeroenPede P.S: ... just checking... have you changed ID to classes? From `#parent` to `.parent` etc... and so on both in HTML and CSS? :) You're welcome